# Documenting the navigation/layout/design of a website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I thought the answer to this would be easy to find but ...

I am using VS 2012 with C# and MVC 3.

Is there a straightforward tool/method to automatically generate the layout/navigation of a website?

Thanks

Comment: Define _"automatically generate"_. Are you looking for code that lists all your controllers and their action methods and builds a menu from that?

Comment: Hi CodeCaster - I just want to represent, in a document, the relationship between the views and the controllers. I use a fair number of partial views and need to see the relationship in a more visual way than just naming conventions. I can manually generate a Visio diagram but wonder if there was a VS tool to help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic that will do it for you.
There are plenty of tools that will generate nice Docs in various formats (including MSDN style) from static analysis of your code.

The one that I personally prefer is Sandcastle and you can read more about it [here](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/).

Hope it helps.